# Throughput coming very low as against the desired RPS-Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, throughput

In Jmeter, how can I achieve a 100 RPS for an http request which is taking an average of 20 seconds response time? The more the thread count I gave, the more response time it took.

What should be the thread count that I should ideally give in this situation? If I am adding a constant throughput timer or throughput shaping timer what should the thread count as well as the settings of the timers?

I have adjusted thread count to 100,250,500, 2500. But it is not giving anything close to 100 RPS. It is about 20/minute that I see.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bottleneck so

1. First of all ensure that you're following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) as it might be the case JMeter configuration is not suitable for kicking off that many threads.
2. Second I would recommend checking whether your system under test has enough headroom in terms of resources (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc.), you can do this using i.e. [JMeter Perfmon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
3. If there is no lack of resources but application performance is not satisfactory, like at point 1 you can check infrastructure configuration (web/application server settings, database settings, etc.) as in majority of cases default configurations are not good enough for high loads. Refer documentation on your infrastructure software for tuning tips.
4. And finally there could be problems with your application code itself, re-run your test having [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) telemetry enabled, this way you will be able to tell for sure where your application spends time and/or resources.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for the quick response. I will do step 1 and step 2. But can you let me know what should be the thread count and timer settings(what type of timer) in my case or how you would set up the test plan? That will be really helpful for my understanding.

Comment: I would recommend going for [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) and [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/). In the Timer you can set desired throughput and connect it to the Thread Group via [feedback loop](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Schedule-Feedback-Function) so JMeter will add more threads if needed in order to reach the target throughput. You can install both the plugins using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)